# How to register a variable to each task dynamically and add those variable in to a list so that i could use it later part of the ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

Real scenario is,

I have n hosts in a inventory group and playbook has to run a specific *command for the specific inventory hostname(done with ansible when condition statement), but whenever the condition met and I need to register a variable for the above *command result.

so this variable creation should be done dynamically and these created variable should be appended into a list and then at end of the same playbook by passing the list to a loop I have to check the job async_status.

So could some one help me here?

```
tasks:
 -name:
  command:
  when: invenory_hostname == x
  async: 360
  poll:0
  regsiter: "here dynamic variable"
-name:
  command:
  when: invenory_hostname == x
  async: 360
  poll:0
  regsiter: "here dynamic variable"
-name:
  command:
  when: invenory_hostname == x
  async: 360
  poll:0
  regsiter: "here dynamic variable" #his will continue based on the requirments
-name: collect the job ids
  async_status:
    jid:{item}
  with_items:"list which has all the dynamically registered variables"
```

Comment: Your example is unclear; your final task is using `async_status`, but you're not spawning any async tasks in your example playbook.

Comment: Thanks to pointing it out, edited not.

Answer (score 2):

If you can write this as a loop instead of a series of independent tasks this becomes much easier. E.g:

```
tasks:
  - command: "{{ item }}"
    register: results
    loop:
      - "command1 ..."
      - "command2 ..."

  - name: show command output
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
    loop: "{{ results.results }}"
```

The documentation on "[Registering variables with a loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop)" discusses what the structure of `results` would look like after this task executes.

---

If you really need to write independent tasks instead, you could use the
`vars` lookup to find the results from all the tasks like this:

```
tasks:
  - name: task 1
    command: echo task1
    register: task_result_1
  - name: task 2
    command: echo task2
    register: task_result_2
  - name: task 3
    command: echo task3
    register: task_result_3

  - name: show results
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ q('vars', *q('varnames', '^task_result_')) }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.cmd }}"
```

---

You've updated the question to show that you're using async tasks, so
that changes things a bit. In this example, we use an `until` loop
that waits for each job to complete before checking the status of the
next job. The `gather results` task won't exit until all the async
tasks have completed.

Here's the solution using a loop:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: run tasks
      command: "{{ item }}"
      async: 360
      poll: 0
      register: task_results
      loop:
        - sleep 1
        - sleep 5
        - sleep 10

    - name: gather results
      async_status:
        jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
      register: status
      until: status.finished
      loop: "{{ task_results.results }}"

    - debug:
        var: status
```

And the same thing using individual tasks:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: task 1
      command: sleep 1
      async: 360
      poll: 0
      register: task_result_1
    - name: task 2
      command: sleep 5
      async: 360
      poll: 0
      register: task_result_2
    - name: task 3
      command: sleep 10
      async: 360
      poll: 0
      register: task_result_3

    - name: gather results
      async_status:
        jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
      register: status
      until: status.finished
      loop: "{{ q('vars', *q('varnames', '^task_result_')) }}"

    - debug:
        var: status
```

Comment: Really thanks lot for your answer, will check this one.

Comment: Note that I wrote this before you updated your question, so while the generate techniques will work just fine, you will probably need to add some logic for waiting for the async jobs to complete.

Comment: Yes thats corect, in my later part of my playbook im using ''untill".